# Sonar : Replace this lambda with a method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, sonarqube

This code sample

```
Collection<Number> values = transform(
        getValuatedObjects(),
        input -> getValueProvider().apply(input).getValue());
```

violates the [Sonarqube rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1612):

> Lambdas should be replaced with method references

Is it a sonar bug?
Or can I really use a method reference?

Comment: It will be easier if you'll post more code...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can’t replace the lambda `input -> getValueProvider().apply(input).getValue()` with a method reference without changing the semantics.

A method reference replace a *single* method invocation, so it can’t simply replace a lambda expression consisting of more than one method invocation.

A lambda expression of the form `input -> getValueProvider().apply(input)` could be replaced by `getValueProvider()::apply` if, and only if, the evaluation time of `getValueProvider()` does not matter as in the lambda form the method is invoked on each lambda body evaluation while for the method reference it is invoked only once and the result captured.

This is similar to the difference between `x -> System.out.println(x)` and `System.out::println` where reading the contents of the field `System.out` happens at different times but usually it doesn’t matter. But you should be aware of the difference.

In your example, a third method `getValue()` is invoked. The only way to express that with method references needs a functional interface like `Function` which has methods like `andThen` and/or `compose`. However, the way Java 8 works, that would require casting the first method reference to the target interface to invoke the combining method which would be by no way easier to read that the lambda expression you have now: `((Function<X,Y>)getValueProvider()::apply).andThen(Y::getValue)` where `Y` is the type, `apply(input)` returns.

Note that the rule says “Replace lambdas with method references *when possible*” which gives you room to say, “well, here it is impossible”, however, I’m not sure how much you can call it a “rule” then…

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So we can say that it's a sonar bug .

Comment: Hi, I do confirm this is indeed a false positive. Ticket have been created to correct this trouble: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-640

Comment: updating old link to the issue : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-640

Answer (score 10):

> list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(element ->
>   operate(element));

replace the above lambda with a method reference.

> list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(this::operate);

Answer (score 6):

if you are coding in java 8 you can use method reference in place of lambda expression for code readable

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
```

replace this lambda with a method reference

```
strList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Replace

```
strList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> inputStringList = List.of("A", "B", "C", "D");
List<String> outputStringList = List.of("C", "D", "E", "F");
assertTrue(outputStringList.stream().anyMatch(inputStringList::contains));
assertTrue(outputStringList.stream().allMatch(inputStringList::contains));
```

This is a sample code to check if content of List is matching against another List using method reference.